# Delete empty folders with a clean or clean-empty task in Grunt.js

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-cli

I am trying to create a Grunt task to clean out a directory of all files, subdirectories, and their files, etc.

I can delete all the files, but the folders always stay.

```
 clean: {
        preview: ["live_preview>/**/*"],
        dist: ["dist/**/*"]
    },
    cleanempty: {
        options: {
            folders: true
        },
        src: ['live_preview/**', 'tmp/**']
    },
```

I am trying to empty out the `live_preview` folder. I have tried several combinations of wildcards.  More puzzling is that the terminal output from `-v` makes it look as though it worked, but the empty folders are still there.

```
Verifying property cleanempty.src exists in config...OK
Files: live_preview, live_preview/fonts, live_preview/images, live_preview/partials,      live_preview/partials/elements, live_preview/scripts, live_preview/scripts/data, live_preview/styles, live_preview/views, tmp, tmp/styles, tmp/styles/live_preview.css, tmp/styles/live_preview.css.map, tmp/styles/theme.css, tmp/styles/theme.css.map -> src
Options: folders
Options: files, folders, force=false, no-write=false
Options: files, folders, force=false, no-write=false
Cleaning live_preview/views...Deleting live_preview/views...OK
OK
Cleaning live_preview/styles...Deleting live_preview/styles...OK
OK
Cleaning live_preview/scripts/data...Deleting live_preview/scripts/data...OK
OK
Cleaning live_preview/partials/elements...Deleting live_preview/partials/elements...OK
OK
Cleaning live_preview/images...Deleting live_preview/images...OK
OK
Cleaning live_preview/fonts...Deleting live_preview/fonts...OK
OK

Done, without errors.
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a Grunt task to clean a temporary directory and the entire folder is removed when I run the task. I assume you're using the same plugin but just to be sure: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-clean

Here is a simplified version of my setup:

```
clean: {
    tests: ['testXmls'] // testXmls is a directory in the top level of my app
}

grunt.registerTask('clean-tests', ['clean:tests']);
```

When I run grunt clean-tests the testXmls directory is deleted with all it's contents.

I think your problem is you're using wildcards in the directory path to tell grunt to delete all subdirectories of live_preview. If you want the top level directory to be deleted then just use that. All the files and directories contained inside will be recursively removed. Think rm -rf

Try:

```
clean: {
    preview: ["live_preview"],
    dist: ["dist"]
}
```

Also, in your terminal, when you see:

```
Deleting live_preview/styles
```

That just means it's deleting the styles directory - it's giving you the whole path to /styles and live_preview is part of that path which is why you're seeing it - there's nothing indicating live_preview itself is deleted. So the output is actually correct.

Answer (score 0):

By the presence of the `folders` option, it looks like you are using the `grunt-cleanempty` package. If so, the problem here is that you have nested its configuration inside the `clean` task and it belongs on its own at the top level. What you have created here is a subtask of `clean` with a `folders` option that it doesn't understand. When you `grunt clean`, the subtask is getting run and those subfolders specified in your `src` are being deleted.

If you aren't using the `grunt-cleanempty` package...you probably should :-)

[Link to grunt-cleanempty](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-cleanempty)